# NFC ISO-DEP keep alive packets on the iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, nfc

I did a simple Android and iOS application based on [nfc-manager](https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager) flutter plugin. And trying to send and receive APDU packets using ISO-DEP tag. I have noticed that Android automatically issues empty isodep keepalive packets:

```
NFCRX: b2 67 c7 - received by the tag. Here b2 is the message and 67c7 is the CRC
NFCTX: a3 - transmitted by the tag (the crc is not included)
NFCRX: b2 67 c7
NFCTX: a3
NFCRX: b2 67 c7
NFCTX: a3
NFCRX: b2 67 c7
NFCTX: a3
NFCRX: b2 67 c7
NFCTX: a3
NFCRX: b2 67 c7
NFCTX: a3
NFCRX: b2 67 c7
NFCTX: a3
NFCRX: b2 67 c7
NFCTX: a3
NFCRX: b2 67 c7
NFCTX: a3
```

These packets can be sent infinitely by Android. But if I use the same application on the IOS there are no keep alive packets and very soon my tag disconnects because of the timeout.
Is there any possibility to enable the keepalive packets on the IOS ?

My code is:

```
    if (Platform.isIOS)
    {
      NfcManager.instance.startSession(
            alertMessage: alertMessage,
            onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
                   
                     tech = Iso7816.from(tag);
                     if (tech is Iso7816) {
                            try{
                                  //send a test APDU message
                                  Uint8List packet = Uint8List.fromList([0x00, 0xD0, 0x00 , 0x00, 0x02, 0x31, 0x00]);
                                  final resp = await Iso7816.from(tag)?.sendCommandRaw(packet);

                                  //using the delay to check if there will be the keepalive packets
                                  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {}); 
                                  String resps = resp.toString();
                             }
                             on PlatformException catch (err) {} 
                             catch (err) {}
                     }
              }
      );
    }
```